# Can I use 2 individual private keys to spend from my Bip32 HD 2 or 2 multisig?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, multi-signature, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

**Example keys are fake:**

If I build a 2 of 2 in Sparrow or any Bip32 Determ wallet, with P2WSH native segwit, and ONLY send funds to the very FIRST receiving address:

m/48'/0'/0'/2'/0/0: bc1qmd5664f2cqtwcn3h8k3e7vhdz4kmpfkw6dereu6t5x2ektjxecnsxhww7c

And I used iancoleman's tool to figure out (and have backed up) the two private keys that Sparrow used under the hood to create the address:

L5DAcZZLG84fcKes8n37SBdD5NEp39rxCDwJMSJnJyohUiNoZFrU -and-
KyeYi1ssJuf85jaLkyyfeYGf31J2gYMPxg7USinAUJ1ePsyZLWrK

And I lose both sets of 24 words, xpubs, public addresses, descriptors and everything else... Can I still retrieve these funds?

Thank you!